# Append File Path to Query String Key That Stores Filename Value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webserver, query-string

I have a

***Browser request URL:*** htpp://example.com/stackoverflow?archive=filename.txt&book=python

As one noticed, the key **archive** stores the value ***filename.txt***. I am in need to append the file path to archive key value using Apache RewriteRule as shown bellow:

The browser request gets

htpp://example.com/stackoverflow?archive=filename.txt&book=python

And Apache rewrites

RewriteRule htpp://example.com/stackoverflow?archive=/path/to/filename.txt&book=python

I added the following lines to a .htaccess file in order to have the URL

htpp://example.com/stackoverflow?archive=/path/to/filename.txt&book=python

resolved by Apache when the URL

htpp://example.com/stackoverflow?archive=filename.txt&book=python is passed to the browser.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)archive=(.+)(&|$) [NC] # archive key can receive any file name in the browser resquest URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /stackoverflow?archive=/path/to/%1&(*.) [R=301,NC,L] # The path of file name is appended to the archive key htpp://example.com/stackoverflow?archive=/path/to/filename.txt&book=python
```

I could not get the path of the file appended to the archive key on the RewriteRule. Any insight on how to achieve that, will be very appreciated it.

Comment: The `%1` will contain what is captured by the first capturing group in the `RewriteCond`. So what is captured by `(^|&)`. You probably want to use a non capturing group instead, so `(?:^|&)`.

Comment: Apart from that the question is unclear to me. Do you want to capture the file name from the query string and then redirect the browser? Or do you want to internally rewrite the filename as a request argument? Your current attempt appears to be a mixture. Please give a clear example _in the question_ (there is an "edit" link) demonstrating what URL is requested and what should happen.

Comment: The file name file.txt is passed in the browser http://example.com/stackoverflow?filename=file.txt (any filename and extension). Thus the variable %{QUERY_STRING} has a key filename and its value file.txt, whatever.png, etc. Now, the only thing I want is to rewrite the URL appending the path of the file to the key filename which value is in QUERY_STRING 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)filename=(.+)(&|$) [NC] # filename key could receive any name and file extension
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /stackoverflow?filename=/path/to/%1 #Apache rewrites the browser URL adding the file path to filename key.

Comment: Once more: please use the "edit" link below the question to revise the question, to add information to it. Do _not_ use comments for that. Thanks.

Comment: What does "The file name file.txt is passed in the browser" actually mean? That you create references inside the html you send to the browser? Or does some client side logic create those references? What is the "key file name" / "filename key"? What "key" should the file path get appended to? And why does that target you rewrite to in your rule _again_ specify the query parameter "filename"?

Comment: When revising your question try not to use fancy technical terms. Just say what link is requested from the browser, what internal resource on the server side it should get rewritten to and what should be visible in the browsers URL bar.